# QT Button position based display

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

I am trying to give option for user to choose a parameter manual and auto with a switch. Based on the selection the display needs to be updated like for manual data entry via a spinbox [and apply] and for auto there shall no spin but just display of quantity. below code my attempt for the same I see no change in display when I change the switch position.

```
        ColumnLayout {
        Switch {
            id: volumeSwitch
            checked: true
            text: qsTr("Manual/Auto")
            onCheckedChanged:
            {
                if(volumeSwitch.checked)
                {
                    Label
                    {
                        text: qsTr("Enter :");
                    }
                    SpinBox
                    {
                        id: spvol
                        stepSize: 50
                        from: 0
                        to: 10000
                        value: 1000
                        scale: 1.2
                        editable: true
                    }
                    Button
                    {
                        text: "Apply"
                        height: spvol.height                            
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Label
                    {
                        text: qsTr("Auto :");
                    }                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That’s not valid code. Declarative QML cannot be placed inside of handlers - only valid and standard JavaScript can go there. So, make sure first what you are trying is syntactically correct. Second, you can use the `visible` property or a Loader to show and hide various parts of your QML document.

Comment: Using the visible property I was able to solve it, thanks @DavidK.Hess